Trying to set camera view on a plane
I making a car animation where I want to set mirror view on the plane
see below images to get clear idea

see that two mirrors showing background view

I want same in this scene .
So there is any option to get this type of view in single render. Also trying to get similar view angle so it look like a real car mirror

Well, just use a reflective shader ? I don't see where the issue lies.

mirror is inside the car and I want view which outside mirror shows .
same for above car , if I directly use reflective shader then it will show inside area of car and not the outside view @Lutzi

Then why not just deleting the parts outside the view ? If at the same time you don't want to use layers and don't want to change anything, I have no solution.

using layers ? can I know more about it? Also car mirrors are convex mirrors . so there is anything to achieve effect like this ? @Lutzi

You can use View Layers to render separately the mirrors and everything else. I'd suggest find some ressources online that matches how you learn, to learn the basics. About convex mirrors, you just have to make your mirror convex. Again, I don't understand what's your issue.

I'm listing 3 ways you can achieve that. I won't give a full rundown, instead I'll provide the general workflow and the terminology so that you can search for ressources and learn the basics.
1. Rework your geometry
You can simply remove the geometry that is obstructing your mirrors. Being outside of the view, it won't have any impact on your render (according to the render you provided). You can delete this geometry, or hide it on render through these options of the Outliner

2. Use View Layers
You can use layers quite the same way as Photoshop for example. Basically, you can render 2 layers :

Everything besides the mirror
Just the mirrors

And composite them inside of the Compositor (put one image over the other). It's a bit complex to setup at first, but it allows you to control just the mirrors after rendering. You could had a tint color to the mirrors (or everything else), darken or brighten it, ...
3. Ray Portal BSDF shader (Cycles only)
A new shader is coming to Blender, called Ray Portal BSDF (currently in beta of Blender 4.2). It allows you to teleport the rays between the mirrors and let's say a few meters behind the car. It works a bit like the portal of the game Portal, you can tell the rays from the mirror to jump and avoid the geometry of the car.
For now it's tricky to setup, I don't recommend it at all for you.
